# heroku nodejs mysql connection ssl local

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I have a project that I'm trying to migrate to mysql hosted on heroku, but locally I always get the following error and I don't know how to solve it.
Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.
Error: Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.
env

```
DB_HOST=
DB_USER=
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_NAME=
DB_PORT=3306
require('dotenv/config');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  client: 'mysql2',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    
  },
  migrations: {
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations'),
  },
  seeds: {
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'seeds'),
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true,
};
require('dotenv/config');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  client: 'mysql2',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    
  },
  migrations: {
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations'),
  },
  seeds: {
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'seeds'),
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true,
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error, it seems that the reason is that you are not using an encrypted connection. It is expected that the error will be digested by adding SSL/TLS settings to the settings(env).

> Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.

Comment: I tried to add some things to the env file, but without success
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"

Comment: locally I can access it, but when I perform the deploy I get the following msg
{"status":"Error","message":"Internal server error - Access denied for user 'matchpointgames'@'3.239.165.24' (using password: YES)"}